# Why is my nested Lua table printing out of order?

Tags: for-loop, lua

Beginner Lua quesiton - I'm just learning lua, and I wrote some code, a nested table to create something like a table with rows and columns.

However, when I iterate through the table using pairs(), it doesn't output in the same order I put it in.  I put it in a Serial, Service Days, Connected, and it's coming out as Service Days, Serial, Connected.  I am at a loss to figuring out why.  I intentionally created the three rows different ways, since I'm just learning and trying to get comfortable with the different ways of dealing with Lua tables...

The code:
    myTable = {}

```
myTable["headerRow"] = {
    Serial = "Serial",
    ServDays = "Service Days",
    Connected = "Connected" }
myTable[1] = {
    Serial = "B9FX",
    ServDays = 7,
    Connected = true }
myTable[2] = {}
myTable[2]["Serial"] = "2SHA"
myTable[2]["ServDays"] = 3
myTable[2]["Connected"] = true

for k, v in pairs(myTable) do
    for k2, v2 in pairs(v) do
        io.write(tostring(v2),",")
    end
    io.write("\n") --End the row 
end
```

The result:

```
c:\lua>lua53 primer.lua
7,B9FX,true,
3,2SHA,true,
Service Days,Serial,Connected,
```

Answer (score 3):

pairs uses the next function. Hence the order of traversal in a generic for loop using the pairs iterator is unspecified.

From the Lua reference manual:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even
>   for numeric indices. (To traverse a table in numerical order, use a
>   numerical for.)
>
> The behavior of next is undefined if, during the traversal, you assign
>   any value to a non-existent field in the table. You may however modify
>   existing fields. In particular, you may clear existing fields.

If you do something like this:

```
myTable[2] = {}
myTable[2]["Serial"] = "2SHA"
myTable[2]["ServDays"] = 3
myTable[2]["Connected"] = true
```

Lua will not remember in which order you asigned values to table keys. It will only map keys to values.